# Firebase Angular Cannot read property 'uid' of null on signOut()

Tags: angular, firebase-authentication

Each time a user logs in, the they get the console error Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'uid' of null
TypeError: Cannot read property 'uid' of null

Each time a user logs out, they get the error
TypeError: Cannot read property 'uid' of null.  Has anyone seen this before?  The code is noted below:

```
logout() {
    this.afAuth.auth.signOut().then(() => {
      this.router.navigate(['/']);
    });
  }

  //// Email/Password Auth ////
  emailLogin(email: string, password: string) {
    return this.afAuth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then((user) => {
        // alert('Welcome to Firestarter!!!');
      })
      .catch((error) => this.handleError(error));
  }

    ////  Get auth data, then get firestore users data
    this.user$ = this.afAuth.authState
      .do(user => this.userUid = user.uid)
      .switchMap((user) => {
        if (user) {
          return this.afs.doc<User>(`users/${user.uid}`).valueChanges();
        } else {
          return Observable.of(null);
        }
      });
```

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Angular, but it seems that you are calling user.uid everytime the authStateChange listener is triggered. This listener is triggered: once the page is loaded and the SDK returns the current session (if any, else it returns null), when the user logs in and when the user logs out for which the listener would also return null. From your description, this seems the scenario you are having. If not, please clarify.

Comment: Yes, that worked.  Thank you.